# Nested defaultdict - Error when updating value

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, nested, defaultdict

I have a dictionary named `dQalpha` and another one named `dQbeta` which calculate the experience of a worker `dQalpha[worker]` and the difficulty of an item `dQbeta[example]` respectively.

I now want to add a new metric named `dQgamma` that calculates the correlation of worker and item, by using `dQgamma[worker][example]` which is a nested defaultdict.

However, if I say `self.dQgamma=defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict))`, I get the error message

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

If I say `self.dQgamma=defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))`, I get this error message

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Can someone help? here's the code:

```python
self.dQalpha={}
self.dQbeta={}
self.dQgamma=defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict))


der = np.zeros_like(x)
i = 0
for worker in self.workers:
    der[i] = -self.dQalpha[worker] 
    i = i + 1
for example in self.examples:
    der[i] = -self.dQbeta[example] 
    i = i + 1
for worker in self.workers:
    for example in self.examples:
        der[i] = self.dQgamma[worker][example] #VALUE ERROR HERE
        i = i + 1

return der
```

**UPDATE**

If I say `self.dQgamma=defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(der.dtype))` , I get

```
NameError: global name 'der' is not defined
```

*EDIT*

```python
  def gradientQ(self, dtype):

        self.optimize_df(x)
        self.dQalpha={}
        self.dQbeta={}
        self.dQgamma=defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(x.dtype)) 
        #ERROR TypeError: first argument must be callable

        for example, worker_label_set in self.e2wl.items():
            dQb = 0
            for (worker, label) in worker_label_set:
                for tlabel in self.prior.keys():
                    sigma = self.sigmoid(self.alpha[worker]*self.expbeta(self.beta[example]))
                    delta = self.kronecker_delta(label,tlabel)
                    dQb = dQb + self.e2lpd[example][tlabel]*(delta-sigma)*self.alpha[worker]*self.expbeta(self.beta[example])\
                          *self.expgamma(self.gamma[worker][example])
            self.dQbeta[example] = dQb - (self.beta[example] - self.priorbeta[example])

        for worker, example_label_set in self.w2el.items():
            dQa = 0
            for (example, label) in example_label_set:
                for tlabel in self.prior.keys():
                    sigma = self.sigmoid(self.alpha[worker]*self.expbeta(self.beta[example]))
                    delta = self.kronecker_delta(label,tlabel)
                    dQa = dQa + self.e2lpd[example][tlabel]*(delta-sigma)*self.expbeta(self.beta[example])\
                          *self.expgamma(self.gamma[worker][example])

            self.dQalpha[worker] = dQa - (self.alpha[worker] - self.prioralpha[worker])


        for worker, example_label_set in self.w2el.items():
            for example, worker_label_set in self.e2wl.items():
                dQg = 0
                for tlabel in self.prior.keys():
                    sigma = self.sigmoid(self.alpha[worker]*self.expbeta(self.beta[example])*\
                                         self.expgamma(self.gamma[worker][example]))
                    delta = self.kronecker_delta(label, tlabel)
                    dQg = dQg + self.e2lpd[example][tlabel]*(delta-sigma)*self.alpha[worker]*self.expbeta(self.beta[example])\
                          *self.expgamma(self.gamma[worker][example])

            self.dQgamma[worker][example] = dQg - (self.gamma[worker][example] - self.priorgamma[worker][example])

def optimize_df(self,x):
    # unpack x
    i=0
    for worker in self.workers:
        self.alpha[worker] = x[i]
        i = i + 1

    for example in self.examples:
        self.beta[example] = x[i]
        i = i + 1

    for worker in self.workers:
        for example in self.examples:
            self.gamma[worker][example] = x[i]
            i = i + 1


    self.gradientQ(x.dtype)

    # pack x
    der = np.zeros_like(x)
    i = 0
    for worker in self.workers:
        der[i] = -self.dQalpha[worker] #Flip the sign since we want to minimize
        i = i + 1
    for example in self.examples:
        der[i] = -self.dQbeta[example] #Flip the sign since we want to minimize
        i = i + 1
    for worker in self.workers:
        for example in self.examples:
            der[i]= self.dQgamma[worker][example] #Flip the sign since we want to minimize #TODO: fix
            i = i + 1
    return der
```

Comment: `defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict))` will give you a `defaultdict` which contains `defaultdict`s which contain `dict`s. When you do `self.dQgamma[worker][example]` you are getting a `dict` object (or a `list` object in the second case), and `der[i]` expects a float value, hence the error. If you want `dQgamma` to be a `defaultdict` containing `defaultdict`s of `float` values, then do `defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(float))` (or even `defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(x.dtype))` if you want to store values of whatever data type `x` has).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Do you know how to resolve the `NameError: global name 'der' is not defined` that occured?

Comment: That is because you do not have any `der` variable defined in your second snippet.

Comment: I define it in the second function called `optimize_df`, as `der = np.zeros_like(x)`, but in the first function, if i do that after defining dQalpha, dQbeta, dQgamma, it doesn't find `x` and then i don't know what to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value returned by `self.dQgamma[worker][example]` is either a dictionary or a list (depending on how you declare it).

You try to affect it to a numpy array expecting scalars.
That's why you have an error.

You should declare `dQgamma` to make it returns a compatible value for your array:

```
self.dQgamma=defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(der.dtype.type))
```

---

### Edit

After all the comments below, I update my answer.

First, actually a [`numpy.dtype`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html)
object is not callable, you have to retrieve its [`type`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.type.html#numpy.dtype.type)
attribute which is callable.
So I edited the code block above to match the right syntax.

Then, here is a complete example on how to be able to use the type of your array inside your function (I changed some namings to match [`PEP8`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) conventions.

```
from collections import defaultdict

import numpy as np

class MyClass:
    def gradient(self, dtype):
        self.d_qgamma=defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dtype.type))

        print("Unset first level value:", self.d_qgamma[0])
        print("Unset second level value:", self.d_qgamma[0][0])

        self.d_qgamma['a'] = defaultdict(dtype.type, {'z': dtype.type(42)})
        print("Set first level value:", self.d_qgamma['a'])

        self.d_qgamma['b']['a'] = dtype.type("42")
        print("Set second level value:", self.d_qgamma['b']['a'])

        print("d_qgamma:", self.d_qgamma)

    def optimize_df(self, x):
        self.gradient(x.dtype)

        der = np.zeros_like(x)
        der[0] = self.d_qgamma['b']['a']
        return der

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("der:", MyClass().optimize_df(np.zeros(4, np.float32)))
```

```
Unset first level value: defaultdict(<class 'numpy.float32'>, {})
Unset second level value: 0.0
Set first level value: defaultdict(<class 'numpy.float32'>, {'z': 42.0})
Set second level value: 42.0
d_qgamma: defaultdict(<function MyClass.gradient.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7fcfd1663050>, {0: defaultdict(<class 'numpy.float32'>, {0: 0.0}), 'a': defaultdict(<class 'numpy.float32'>, {'z': 42.0}), 'b': defaultdict(<class 'numpy.float32'>, {'a': 42.0})})
der: [42.  0.  0.  0.]
```

As you can see, you pass `x.dtype` of type `numpy.dtype` to your `gradient` function.
Then, you can use this `dtype` object and retrieve its `type` attribute, which is callable, to:

- pass it to your `defaultdict` constructor

  `self.d_qgamma=defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dtype.type))`
- cast any value that you would like to store

  `self.d_qgamma['b']['a'] = dtype.type("42")`

  Here the string `"42"` is converted to `float` with value `42.0`.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, although i have another issue which may be silly, but it says that `NameError: global name 'der' is not defined`. Because i define `self.dQgamma=defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(der.dtype))` in one function and then calculate `der` in another. I updated my question, so that you see how it looks like.

Comment: @joasa This is more related to the global use of your code... Do you know beforehand the type of `x` and so of `der`. If yes, replace `der.dtype` by this type. Else you have to rethink your code, either to pass `x` or `der` to `gradientQ` or something like that to be able to know the type when required.

Comment: I edited the code. In my `gradientQ`, i want to call the other function `optimize_df`, but the problem is that `optimize_df` gets an argument (x), which i don't know how to define within the `gradientQ` function. I mean, since i call `optimize_df`, shouldn't it be automatically ok with its x argument?

Comment: @joasa This is not the right solution. `optimize_df` already calls `gradientQ`. Here you have a infinite loop (`gradientQ` calling `optimize_df` calling `gradientQ`, etc.). Moreover how can you call `optimize_df(x)` in `gradientQ` while you don't have `x` in `gradientQ`? Instead redefine `gradientQ` as `def gradientQ(dtype)`, call it in `optimize_df` as `self.gradientQ(x.dtype)` and use the `dtype` argument in `gradientQ` to build your `defaultdict`.

Comment: i tried your suggestion, if i understood it correctly, and now i see this error `TypeError: first argument must be callable`. Why it's not callable?